# When I select the Pricing & Distribution tab in the Google Play Developer console, it displays 'Loading'

Tags: google-play

I'm trying to publish an app that is based on a free app that supports in-app billing and which is already published. Rather than use in-app billing in the new app, I decided to remove it and make it a paid app (the difference between the two apps is that the paid app has some enhancements that I want to get paid for).

So I created a new product in Google Play, different package name, etc. Everything went fine until I selected Pricing & Distribution, set the pricing ($0.99) and the distribution. When I tried to publish, I get the Android mascot with the text "Loading" alongside it and it stays like this. The app never appears in searches, even when it's enclosed in quotes. The original app does come up, but not the new one (the difference between the names is that the new one has the word "Pro" after it). And yes, the package names are different.

One more thing: when I uploaded the APK to the store, I got a warning about the app using in-app billing (which it does not) but there is no billing permission in the manifest. Since it was a warning and I don't do in-app billing, I ignored it and continued with the upload. I don't think this has anything to do with the "Loading" problem because it was happening before I removed in-app billing.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a google service issue.

Comment: @323go: Are you saying that because you don't have an answer, I should contact Google for help?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should contact google, because you have a very specific problem with their service.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the problem somehow resolved itself. The app is visible in searches, although the "Loading" message in Pricing and Distribution is still stuck. Very weird.